# Add geom_point for specific geom_area in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

With sample and code below, I'm trying to reproduce the effect of an image by adding geom_point for only type 3 data as shown in the end of this question:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
df <- structure(list(date = c("2021-07-31", "2021-08-31", "2021-09-07", 
"2021-09-14", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-30", "2021-10-7", "2021-10-14", 
"2021-10-21", "2021-10-31", "2021-11-30", "2021-12-31", "2022-1-31", 
"2022-2-28"), value = c(190.3, 174.9, 163.2, 168.4, 168.6, 168.2, 
163.5, 161.6, 172.9, 166.5, 175.2, 197.7, 212.1, 177.9), type = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
df$type <- as.factor(df$type)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
setDT(df, key = "date")
types.extend <- c(1)
new.values <- df[, .SD[1], by = .(type)][, type := shift(type, type = "lag")][type %in% types.extend,]
# bind the new value to your original data
df <- rbind(df, new.values)
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x=date, y=value, group=type, color = type, fill = type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.4, position = "identity") +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("1" = "gray", "2" = "red", "3" = "blue"), 
                     aesthetics = c("color", "fill"), name = "type") +
  theme_bw()
```

Out:

[image]

As I add `geom_point(size=2)` to the code, it add points for all data points, how could I add geom_point only for data's type is 3? Sincere thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `data` argument of `geom_point` to restrict the points being plotted.
So replace your `geom_point(size=2)` call with `geom_point(data=df[type==3], size=2)`

(note this syntax only works because per the question `df` is a `data.table`, use `df[df$type==3,]` otherwise)

[image]

An alternative, if you didn't want the legend to include the points for the other two types would be to set the shape to `NA` for the types you didn't want to include:

```
 geom_point(size=2, aes(shape=type)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("1"=NA, "2"=NA, "3"=19))+
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, to go further, if I'd like to plot the last datapoint of type 2 + datapoints of type 3 as shown in the example figure?

Comment: geom_point(data=df[type==3 | date==max(df[type==2]$date)],size=2, aes(shape=type)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("1"=NA, "2"=19, "3"=19))+...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your question but try :

```
ggplot(data = df, 
       aes(x=date, y=value, group=type, color = type, fill = type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.4, position = "identity") +
  geom_point(data = filter(df, type == 3), aes(x=date, y=value, group=type), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("1" = "gray", "2" = "red", "3" = "blue"), 
                     aesthetics = c("color", "fill"), name = "type") +
  theme_bw()
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. To go further, if I'd like to plot the last datapoint of type 2 + datapoints of type 3 as shown in the example figure?